# Parent directory in Excel (no VBA)

Tags: string, excel, search, directory, excel-formula

How do I set a cell’s value to the parent of the directory the file is in?

I’ve got a tedious and repetitious task ahead of me, and I’m trying to automate as much of this as possible—but VBA isn’t allowed.

I’m going to have a directory tree of Excel spreadsheets, looking something like this:

```
C:\…\Parent1\Dir2\File3.xlsx
   …\Parent4\Dir5\File6.xlsx
   …
```

I need a formula which will extract the *parent* directory, *e.g.*, `Parent1` or `Parent4` in this example.

[*Note*: *The file and directory names do not follow any particular convention; suggestions to look for numbers will match this anonymized example but won’t help me.*]

---

Notes:

I have found elsewhere on the ’net the following formulae, which I’ve needed as well and which might point to the solution.

- The current sheet name:
  `= RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1), LEN(CELL("filename",A1)) - FIND("]", CELL("filename",A1)))`
- The current file name:
  `= MID(CELL("filename",A1), FIND("[", CELL("filename",A1)) + 1, FIND(".", CELL("filename",A1)) - (FIND("[", CELL("filename",A1)) + 1))`
- The current directory name (from [MrExcel.com](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/360121-formula-display-parent-folder-name-2.html#post1780788)):
  `= TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CELL("filename",A1), FIND("[", CELL("filename",A1), 1) - 2), "\", REPT(" ",100)), 100))`
  The poster explained his method thus:

  > It works by getting the DIR and replacing all "\" with 100 spaces. It then grabs the right 100 chars which will be a bunch of spaces and the final DIR name then it trims off the preceding spaces.

This last feels like it should be adaptable to extracting the parent directory, but I haven’t figured out how to write this adaptation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It goes unsaid that this formula will only work in a `saved` file.

`=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CELL("filename",A1), FIND("[", CELL("filename",A1), 1) - 2),"\",REPT(" ",100)),200),100))`

**Screenshot**:

[image]

**LOGIC**:

To find a string between two characters, use this. (Finding between say "\")

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",100)),200),100))
```

The below gives the full path

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename",A1), FIND("[", CELL("filename",A1), 1) - 2)
```

For example: `C:\Temp\Folder 1`

So just insert the second one in the first formula